# Singleton generator, multiple consumers

Tags: python, thread-safety, generator

I have singleton which is accessed from different threads. This singleton is providing data with a generator. The generator should be *fully* consumed by the thread accessing the data. Each thread accessing the data should consume a *new* generator. This is my code:

```
from   datetime import datetime
import threading
import time

class MySingletonCls:

    def get_data(self, repeat):
        self.nr = 0
        for x in xrange(repeat):
            time.sleep(0.001)
            self.nr += 1
            yield x

_my_singleton = None

def MySingleton():
    global _my_singleton
    if _my_singleton == None:
        _my_singleton = MySingletonCls()
    return _my_singleton

def test_singleton():
    def worker():
        singleton = MySingleton()
        cnt = 0
        for x in singleton.get_data(100):
            cnt += 1
        print singleton.nr, cnt
    threads = []
    num_worker_threads = 5
    for i in range(num_worker_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

test_singleton()
```

I would expect that each worker has received 100 entries, and actually that is the case. But accessing the counter in the singleton gives me very strange numbers. This is the output of my program:

```
457 100
468 100
470 100
471 100
475 100
```

What is going on here? How many entries is generating the singleton generator, for each thread? Why is the singleton counter showing this strange values? How can I make this thread-safe?

Comment: Of course 100 100 for all threads! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is only one instance of the singleton, the `nr` attribute is shared across all generators.  Even though a new generator is created on each call, they all use the same `nr` attribute.  So whenever any thread consumes an element from the generator, it increases `nr`, and whenever a new generator is created, it resets `nr`.  These increments and resets are happening unpredictably across the threads.

If you want each call to `get_data` to yield a fully independent generator, you can't have them all relying on the same `nr` attribute.  Note that the generator will be "paused" at each yield and will retain the function's state at that time, so you don't really need to use an attribute at all.  You could just use a local variable:

```
def get_data(self, repeat):
    nr = 0
    for x in xrange(repeat):
        time.sleep(0.001)
        nr += 1
        yield x
```

However, it's not clear what you're trying to do with `self.nr` anyway, since you don't yield it in the generator.  There's no way to allow multiple threads to mutate the singleton object at will and still get consistent results from all of them.  If actions in threads result in changes to the singleton's object state, you can never tell when these changes will take place.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. But I have an additional problem: I need to access nr from outside the singleton. That is why I need the attribute. The generator can not return values, so a local variable will not do. Any idea on how could I implement this?

Comment: You need to provide more information about how and why you're accessing `nr` from outside.  You need to explain what effect (if any) you want your threads to have on `nr`, and what output you want.

Comment: In your comment on your original post, you said you want to see "100 100" for all threads.  How do you expect this to work when each thread is affecting the same `nr` variable?  You need to say what `nr` is and how you want threads to interact with it.  Do you want each thread to get a separate "copy" of `nr`?

Comment: My real implementation is based on a couchdb view. The data singleton is providing a page of data as requested by the workers, which are calling the get_data function with some parameters (page number, size of page, and some filtering data). The singleton is generating the data as requested, and must also provide some statistics (the attributes), like first entry index, total number of rows in view, number of documents read (normally the same as the number of documents requested, but the database could have little amount of documents). So I need some state in the singleton.

Comment: Why are you using a singleton?  If different threads are requesting different data, and each request needs different statistics associated with it, then it seems like each request should get its own object.  You could still possibly use a singleton for the data itself, but use separate objects for each request.  It's a little hard to say for sure without seeing more specifics.

Comment: Mmmm ... I think you got me onto something there. Thanks. I can unfortunately not provide more code because it is too big. It is also completely unpolished (custom logging entries, ...), so it would be a mess to provide it in full.

Answer (score 1):

In `MySingletonCls.get_data`, `self` always refers to the same object so `self.nr` names the same object slot in each thread.

That means that `singleton.nr` is reset to 0 each time a thread starts, and is then incremented in parallel by each thread.  You're seeing numbers from 457 to 475 printed because the last thread starts when the other threads are collectively 25 through their iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You are yielding `x` while you are printing `self.nr`. Each time a new worker is generated, it is setting `self.nr` to 0, then starts counting from 0 to 100.

So, `self.nr` is reset every now and then, and because `self` will be the same across all the workers, it is incremented `(num of workers)*(100)`. So, `self.nr` should be equal to that, taking into account the number of times it was reset to `0`. You do the calculation, including the time between each "reset". :D, but I guess this is your problem.